# Testing ASP.NET Core app using Protractor in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, protractor-net

I've got a asp.net core application which uses angular4 as client frontend and asp.net core for the service api. I've had [end-to-end unit-testing up and running while using Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675510/testing-asp-net-core-app-using-protractor-in-visual-studio-2015).

Since I switched to Visual Studio **2017** I can't get the tests to use protractor anymore.

First problem: For protractor I need the full .net framework, for hosting my app I want to use .NetCoreApp 1.1. And Visual Studio 2017 does only support using one Framework. There are [tricks by editing the proj-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670048/how-to-target-multiple-frameworks-in-vs2017-final), but even then I could not even compile my test project to use protractor.

So: Has anyone been able to run unit Tests using protractor in Visual Studio 2017? Any pointers about it, maybe you can point me to a website containing a sample?

Comment: __For protractor I need the full .net framework, for hosting my app I need to use asp.net core__ They are completely unrelated to each other. Full .NET Framework is a runtime, ASP.NET Core is just a webstack. ASP.NET Core runs on both, .NET Core and the full .NET Framework. And  btw. that "tricks" are no tricks, its the way it was intended and only required when you target .NETStandard (or .NET Core) **AND** .NET Framework 4.x.

Comment: That's because NuGet/The Applciation doesn't which version of the libraries to restore/use when you start it. ASP.NET Core has some native dependencies, like Libuv for Kestrel etc. these depend on OS and architecture (x64 or x86)